# Large Batches of Indexing vs. Trickling Requests

Tags: elasticsearch

We are currently using an Elasticsearch cluster in production for storing product data. As we get updates to the products, we perform continuous updates to the elasticsearch cluster, of course we use the batch requests. But I'm curious if the continuous updates cause a significant performance disadvantage as opposed to creating a large batch update every 30 minutes or so.

I can also increase the refresh setting on the index to 30 minutes as well but not sure if there will be a significant performance increase without doing tons of load testing.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: ES has no issues with continuous updates, whether batch or not. Of course, most of the time, it's better to resort to bulk updates than sending individual documents. Have you noticed any issues in the way you're doing it so far?

Comment: I mean elasticsearch is performing well but I'm not sure if there is a best practice for optimizing for search performance

Comment: optimizing search performance while you're indexing? do you see search perf issue while indexing?